# How to use file_get_contents on Ajax site

Tags: php, html, ajax, file-get-contents

When you use `file_gets_contents($website)` or [**cURL**](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download)  to load a website, does it load the whole website? I am mostly interested about using **cURL**.

I am using it to load a webpage that then gets some contents such as price using AJAX and it has some problems getting the prices.

When I use file_get_contents, does it load as normally as a whole website does on a browser plus the stuff loaded using Ajax?

Comment: Better think why do you need it. There is no perfect and 100% error-less solution. Maybe you need first to load main page and then prices pieces? That seems to be better and more stable than creating virtual enviroment to execute JS.

Answer (score 4):

No. Using `file_get_contents()` will only return the page contents, it will not execute any JavaScript on the page itself. The analog of this behaviour is almost equivalent to "View Page Source" in a browser.

Comment: How can one execute Javascript? I'm actually using cURL to load the site but I mentioned file_get_contents() because that is the most commonly used. I have edited the question.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php). Essentially, you would need to programmatically ape a browser environment, which understands how to parse and execute JavaScript.

Comment: @plasmid87 is there such a library that is pure PHP? That is.... no coding in another language.

Comment: As @SteAp mentioned in his answer, there is the V8 JavaScript engine. Personally, if I were in your position, I would be tempted to manually identify the AJAX calls in the page you're requesting, identify where the values should be displayed, and then make the calls from your server to the AJAX endpoints. You could then insert the values in the resulting HTML on your server.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet

```
$website = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
file_gets_contents($website)
```

**loads the result of the HTTP-request, nothing else**. Thus, the call loads the source of the html-page returned by the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

Especially, `file_gets_contents()` **does not load stuff referenced** by the page pointed to by `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

**Evaluating JavaScript code using PHP**

In case you'd like to **evaluate JavaScript inside of HTML-code using a PHP-script**, you'd probably wish to use the [V8 JavaScript engine](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php), which needs to be compiled into your PHP-binary:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Find an example how to [use the V8 JavaScript engine here](http://php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php).

Comment: So it will not load any stuff that the Javascript or JQuery loads after the whole document has been loaded`($(document).ready())` ?

It loads the website as if Javascript has not been loaded for the browser? Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right! file_gets_contents() gets the HTTP-reply. Since the reply does not 'pass' the browser, no JavaScript gets executed.

Comment: Same functionality. More or less all such stuff loads the pure page.