# Get page contents after javascript prints

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the contents of a page with `file_get_contents` but instead of getting the code for the javascript, is there a way to get what it prints?

```
<?php
$streams=file_get_contents("URL");
$myFile = "filename.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = $streams;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Because JavaScript modifies the DOM at the browser and you cannot read the client from the server this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am told it is possible, the answers are already on Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699303/2119863

http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

However, please think if it's a something you really must have. Since you want to get changed/dynamic results from a file, then include a 'script.js.php' file where the PHP will do the javascript work. JS is for user interaction, not server ;(