# PHP : Curl a page, apply javascript and save result

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I research a PHP library that allows to execute javascript code on html content to obtain HTML modified content without browser.

The steps are :

1. Get a page with curl or file get content
2. Apply a javascript script to the page.
3. Save the result page in a file on server.

All in one php script.

**Edit :**

My goal is to get the result of a php web page after applying a javascript function on this page to change some things.

Is there a PHP library that allows to execute the javascript code of a page Without going through a browser, and return the results in HTML?

Comment: php doesn't run javascript, browsers do.

Comment: yes it is possible ! have you tried that ?

Comment: i can't help but think that a platform other than php would be better-suited for your task. you can do #1 and #3 in JS, but you can't do #2 in php...

Comment: May be `NodeJs` not `php`

Comment: I have found this : https://www.apifier.com/

Comment: https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer is just the important part of apifier and it runs in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution here :

[Execute javascript in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php/2699303#2699303)

Using HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs".

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/