# Curl Post Response in PHP not showing full html

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Curl Info shows its successful :

```
array(37) { ["url"]=> string(50) "http://abcd.bd/abcd.php" ["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" ["http_code"]=> int(200) ["header_size"]=> int(318) ["request_size"]=> int(403) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(2.218) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(1.0E-6) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.078) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.078) ["size_upload"]=> float(637) ["size_download"]=> float(5878) ["speed_download"]=> float(2650) ["speed_upload"]=> float(287) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(637) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.078) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) ""  ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(80) ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "10.102.11.131" ["local_port"]=> int(54537) ["http_version"]=> int(2) ["protocol"]=> int(1) ["ssl_verifyresult"]=> int(0) ["scheme"]=> string(4) "HTTP" ["appconnect_time_us"]=> int(0) ["connect_time_us"]=> int(78000) ["namelookup_time_us"]=> int(1) ["pretransfer_time_us"]=> int(78000) ["redirect_time_us"]=> int(0) ["starttransfer_time_us"]=> int(78000) ["total_time_us"]=> int(2218000) }
```

but my curl_exec($ch)
returns only header and footer.
Table data is not showing up.

I have tried all the option but still no luck .

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url_register.'a.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_register.'a.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html; charset=UTF-8'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

FYI The response page I want contain

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

at top.

I dont know whats wrong . It should be simple.
what i am missing here???

Comment: Does it really contain `"<'`? That's not valid HTML. Or did you add that quote to keep SO from interpreting what you wrote as HTML? The best way to do that is to put the output into a code block.

Comment: Do you have `echo $result;`? Have you used `View Source` to see what it's actually echoing?

Comment: Maybe the page uses JavaScript to fill in the table data. `curl` doesn't execute JS.

Comment: @Barmar any solution for this?? If it is JS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize

Comment: I have tried echo $result , var_dump and view source . And Found no table data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726340/php-curl-a-page-apply-javascript-and-save-result

Comment: Do you see JavaScript that's performing AJAX calls to get the table data?

Comment: @Barmar Please check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/x3qp519h/

Comment: If it's using AJAX, you can just see what URL it's sending the AJAX request to, and use `curl` to make the same queries in your script.

Comment: @Barmar I just put all the information in JS. Just submit and see the page.

Comment: I don't understand what that fiddle is supposed to do. There's no form to submit.

Comment: Browse the link and submit the data.

Comment: Are you filling in the `value_s` field of the form correctly when you send the curl request? It's a CAPTCHA that requires you to read the equation in the previous column and fill in the result. So if it says `7 + 9` you have to put `16` in that field.

Comment: Yes. I did and got 200 response . Thats not a problem . I got response  of the desired page except the table data.

Comment: There's no JavaScript in the response page, so that's not the problem. Are you sure you're sending the correct cookie data? You have to first download the form to get the cookies, then submit the form with the same cookies.

Comment: That could be a problem , coz I'm using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 1);

Comment: You should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);` just like when you're submitting the form.

Comment: $cookie should be an empty text file right??

Comment: Right, it will be filled in when you make requests that send back cookies.

Comment: can you show me a link . I dont know How to filled in? Filled with what data??         I am trying this :                      $cookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . session_name() . '; path=/';

Comment: `$cookie` contains a filename. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` means that it should save the returned cookies there, and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` means it should send the cookies from the file.

Comment: You don't fill it in at all. When you request `index.php` it fills it in, and then when you submit the form it sends the cookies back.

Comment: It's just like using cookies to login to a web site. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049393/using-php-curl-to-login-to-my-websites-form for examples.

Comment: @Barmar its not working .  check my full code :  https://pastebin.com/WYWkP6yW