# How to call Javascript function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function

I'm trying to call a Javascript function from a file called scripts.js, in a PHP file.

I have this on the head of the PHP file:

```
<script type="JavaScript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

This in scripts.js:

```
function getStuff(id, equipaNome) {
document.getElementById("seed" . id).innerHTML = equipaNome;
}
```

And this is from the PHP file again, with the script at the bottom:

```
echo "<table align='center'>";
    echo"<tr id='" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "'>";
    echo"<td width='30px' id=seed'" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "'>" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "</td>";
    echo"<td width='30px' id=nome'" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "'>" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "</td>";
    echo"<td width='30px'>-</td>";
    $sql = "select seed from equipaEvento where equipaID='" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "'AND eventoID='" . $_GET['id'] . "';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $equipaseed = $row['seed'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Seed: " . $equipaseed;
            $sql2 = "select equipaNome from equipa where equipaID='" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "';";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                    $equipanome = $row['equipaNome'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Nome: " . $equipanome;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<script>
    getStuff('" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "', '" . $equipaseed . "');
    </script>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

The function isn't working, I think the function and/or the script in the PHP file might be incorrect but I don't know where.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute javascript in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php)

Comment: PHP is executed on the server BEFORE the page is sent to the client. JavaScript is executed on the client side AFTER PHP has built the page. You can't have your JS and PHP interact directly, you need to use AJAX to do things like that.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins ... I'm not certain that's what he's trying to do: `echo "<script>getStuff('" . $arrayPart1[$index] . "', '" . $equipaseed . "'); </script>";` sort of implies that he's merely trying to pre-fill a JS function with data generated from PHP which *would* work...

Comment: For one, you're rewriting `$equipaseed` on each `while` loop. Also, the table cells would render as `id=nome'fooIndex'` which is invalid HTML.  That said, do you get a SQL error, a PHP error, or a JS error? If you're simply outputting funnies, have you looked at the HTML source of what ends up in the browser? Also, perhaps use `+` instead of `.` to concatenate in your JS function.

Comment: This code was working previously. I had everything like it is right now and the function was doing something, not what I needed it to do, but it was working. I don't know why it's not working now, possibly some writting mistake somewhere.

Comment: It looks like you've embedded your `<script> ... </script>` block inside the HTML body and it just calls a function. That function calls `document.getElementById()` **but** it's being executed inline (as the page loads) so, odds are, the id you're trying to get doesn't exist in the DOM yet; try executing the function, with some dummy data, inside a `document.onload` type call... on closer inspection - it's also full of syntax errors; turn on some debugging.

Comment: Yes, you have to seriously think about "What is the role of the server?" and "What is the role of the client?".  Php just sends the HTML source code to client, for php this is just a string of characters, php doesn't care.  It's the webbrowser that turns source code into a web page, including css and javascript.  Think about what your end goal is, and reformulate your question

Comment: Ok, got it. I've been thinking of another way to do this and I think I have it figured out. Thanks for the help anyway :)