# How do I get page elements from remote URL that uses dynamic Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to parse out some product information from webstores like Target and such, but they're using javascipt to build their page dynamically and the html I'm receiving via cUrl is very different than the final code. When I view the source code it matches what I receive with cUrl, but when I use the document inspector, I see a mostly normal page with images, H1 tags and such which is what I need to be able to grab and parse. Is there a way to pull down what the page looks like after the JS has run?

To clarify, I am not scraping these sites. I just have a bookmarklet that adds an item that the user is looking at to a wishlist. The only information I'm trying to get is a product title, a description, and preferably an image. This only occurs when a user of my site is browsing and clicks the bookmarklet.

Comment: maybe they dont want you stealing there content?

Comment: If you want to "pull down what the page looks like after the JS has run" you will need to run the javascript and only then parse the page.

Comment: Sheesh, why does everyone assume he/she's trying to "steal" content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute javascript in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php)

Comment: because its specficly against targets terms. that's why @Jacob

Comment: @Jacob - unless op has permission from target to scrape their site, it is stealing. scraping the site is a way to get around any developer agreements which would have been required to use the api.

Comment: unlawful or prohibited uses "make any use of data extraction, scraping, mining or other data gathering tools, or create a database by systematically downloading or storing Site content, or otherwise scrape, collect, store or use any Content, product listings, descriptions, prices or images, except pursuant to the limited license granted by these Terms & Conditions;"

Comment: If it's against the terms & conditions, it's definitely the wrong way to go about things, but I wouldn't assume malicious intent here, could just be unawareness of the T&C. I'm just annoyed at the lack of civility.

Comment: jacob, you're the only one making assumptions. i simply used the correct terminology. i have no idea how targets product data could possibly be used maliciously lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about it wrong.

Scraping a site is not a reliable data source. Major retailers like Target all have APIs which you can use to get product info. They want you to have this information. No reason to try to steal it.

- [Target Product API](https://developer.target.com/)
- [WalMart Product API](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/)

Google for others.

---

However, to answer your actual question, if you wanted to scrape a site AFTER Javascript had changed the DOM, you could use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to run the code on the website and then scrape it, or if this is for personal use, a [userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en) might suffice.

**Edit**

After seeing your edit I gather that your bookmarklet sends an AJAX request  to your server with the URL they're looking at, at which point you cURL the page with PHP and scrape it for product info (scraping is a correct term for that BTW). If this is not the situation please make your question clearer. The better you explain the less we have to assume.

If this assumption is accurate, then you should parse the data in the bookmarklet code and send that back to the server instead of/in addition to the url. Javascript is much better suited for scraping pages than PHP is it saves a redundant HTTP call. IMO, jQuery is especially helpful, I wrote [this little script](http://geneticcoder.com/pages/jsbtn.php) to generate bookmarklets that include jQuery, maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: The API idea is exellent though doesn't work for every site and still won't work for webpages that don't have APIs. The idea of using my bookmarklet itself to find the data and send it back is perfect. Together, this is exactly what I need! Thank you!