# PHP DOM - How to parse <li> tag with specific class and print its "title" attribute

Tags: php, class, parsing, dom, html-lists

I've got a bunch of data like this:

```
<div id="div_id">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="blue" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="black" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="white" title="any_title"></li></a>

        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="blue" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="black" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="white" title="any_title"></li></a>

        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="blue" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="black" title="any_title"></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="any_id" class="white" title="any_title"></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I extract the "title" values of every "li" tags that contains the "blue" class?

I'm  new and I've been trying this for days, any help would be great.

Comment: Show what you've tried during those days. We're not just going to do it for you, but we'll help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: The selector `li.blue` will find all the tags you want, and `$el->getAttribute('title')` will return the title of an element.

Comment: @Marcel , if my code helped you then please mark it as accepted to close this thread or post comment to express whats not clear. Thanks,

Comment: Your HTML is wrong by the way. It should definitly be `<ul><li><a ...></a></li></ul>`

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, friend. I tried so many different codes found here on StackOverflow that it would be impossible to explain, as I understand very little of them myself. I tried using built-in DOM and 3rd party PHP Simple DOM HTML Parser. Abhay Maurya's answer below seems simple enough for me to implement it, I'm just trying to figure it out how to point to the remote url and how to output/print as plaintext.

Comment: @Blackbam: Unfortunately the code is hosted on a third-party website I do not control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Simple PHP DOM Parser:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('li.blue') as $li) {
    echo $li->title . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason, when I search for the "blue" class I get every li tag of all classes. If I search for "white" or "black" classes I got no results, blank page.

Comment: Some context:

This is the website I'm trying to scrap: http://www.infraero.gov.br/situacaoaeroporto

I'm trying to get the names (li titles) of the red dots (original class name: pontoVermelho).

Comment: The web site uses AJAX to change the classes. PHP doesn't execute Javascript, so it just gets the original HTML before anything is changed.

Comment: Got it! Do you know any other way I can implement this to grab the classes after it's changed? Thanks.

Comment: You should check whether they provide a public API that you can call to get the information.

Comment: There isn't. The information is public domain by Brazilian law but there is no machine-readable data available.

Is there a way to parse data after AJAX modifies it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that but I would advise you to use jQuery as its simple:

```
$('li.blue').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');//do whatever with title variable
    //you can append this title into body of html under some special class and then you can style it later like this:
    $('body').append('<span class="title">'+title+'</span>');
```

//Now you can style it however using css by addressing .title class
    })

Code is pretty much self explanatory, you loop through all `li` elements which has `blue` class and extract `title` attribute of it.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. How can I point this to the remote url hosting the html file? Also, how do I output the title variable as plaintext or something that I can style with CSS later. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Marcel I answered ou question about adding it as plain text and styling it later in HTML page. I am not sure about your comment : "How can I point this to the remote url hosting the html file?" Maybe you could explain what do you mean.

Comment: This is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: @ Barmar , Frankly man, To manipulate client side data with server side script is considered highly bad practice so maybe OP has marked it PHP question but that doesn't mean it should also be answered in same wrong way as OP wants. Better solution should be provided and encouraged because here we all are to learn to code in right way,

Comment: @Barmar: Hello friend, could you help me to find a PHP solution using DOM? The file is hosted on a remote server and the main goal is to get the title attribute of the li tags classed as blue. Print that attribute value. I'm a newb so I would need more detailed instructions if possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AbhayMaurya He's not manipulating client-side data. He's scraping a web site.

Comment: @AbhayMaurya: If this can be done with jQuery, I don't mind, as it is the most simple approach I found. The code I provided as example is hosted on a remote server, so I need to write that URL somewhere, right? Sorry for the dumb questions but what's the full code I need for this to work? Just to clarify, I'm pasting this code onto a Wordpress theme index.php file. Thanks again.