# Is there any way to make Javascript work in DOMPDF-generated PDFs?

Tags: javascript, html, dompdf

I am currently testing DOMPDF and got it working quite nice for my purposes, including CSS styling, displaying content fetched from a mysql database etc.

Now I tried to use some Javascript, but it doesn't work. I used a very simple script for testing:

HTML somewhere on the page:

```
<div id='mydiv1' style='width: 100%;height:20px;background:#ddd;'></div>
```

The JS (just above the closing `</body>` tag (but I also tried it right after the opening `<body>` tag):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('mydiv1').innerHTML = 'this is a test';
</script>
```

When I echo this page in the browser (I am echoing a variable which contains the complete HTML/PHP page), that text appears in the DIV. When I put the same variable in DOMPDF's `loadHtml` and then render and output it, the script-generated text doesn't appear in the PDF (the rest of the page does).

So my question is: Is there any way to make Javascript work in DOMPDF-generated PDFs?

Comment: This reply to [Execute javascript in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2699303/5217142)  uses [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to generate HTML from a web page and may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, DOMPDF doesn't support javascript. You may consider looking at something like [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs), which can be [used to save pdf files](https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g/use-phantomjs-to-create-pdfs-from-html), as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the most important thing for me is the PHP functionality and also the possibility to fetch content via MYSQL, and it seems this is not possible to do with phantomjs.

Comment: I just saw this line on the DOMPDF "Features" page in Github: "inline PDF Javascript support (with scripts compatible with the PDF Documents API)". But I suppose that only means JS stuff that can be directly written into HTML tags, if at all (?)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they're talking about embedding javascript into the PDF file itself, though this is [only supported by some pdf viewers](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a DomPDF option to turn on inline javascript:

$isJavascriptEnabled = true;

Heres an example of how to use the DomPDF options:

```
$HTML = <<<HTML
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
some html
</body>
<script> somejs </script>
</head>
</html>
HTML;

require_once "sites/all/libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', TRUE);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->load_html($HTML);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('blah.pdf');
```

I took this from DomPDF's options page: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Options.php

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! However, this option *is* enabled/true by default, also in the testing situation which I desribed above, and that didn't work...