# How to convert jquery quiz result to pdf on click?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, pdf

I am trying to create a jquery quiz, I want the user to download the result in pdf on click, after googling I found that I should use [dom pdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) library to convert HTML to pdf.

Here is a working demo quiz [quiz demo](http://jsfiddle.net/81rws4xp/)

Here is my solution.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="quiz">
            <div id="questions">This is a quiz about Turkey, click start to begin
                <div id="start">Start</div>
            </div>
            <div name="answersFrame" id="answersFrame" class="choices">
                <input type="radio" name="answers" class="choices" value=0>
                <p id="zero" class="pickone"></p>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="answers" class="choices" value=1>
                <p id="one" class="pickone"></p>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="answers" class="choices" value=2>
                <p id="two" class="pickone"></p>
                <br/>
                <input type="radio" name="answers" class="choices" value=3>
                <p id="three" class="pickone"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="next">next</div>
        </div>
        <div id="table">
            <div id="score"></div>
            <table id="results">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Your Answer</th>
                        <th>Correct Answer</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="row" name=0>
                        <td>Turkey's capital</td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="userAnswer" value=0></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="correctAnswer" value=0></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row" name=1>
                        <td>Turkey's founding date</td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="userAnswer" value=1></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="correctAnswer" value=1></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row" name=2>
                        <td>Turkey's population</td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="userAnswer" value=2></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="correctAnswer" value=2></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row" name=3>
                        <td>Istanbul's population</td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="userAnswer" value=3></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p class="correctAnswer" value=3></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <button class="getResult">Result </button>
```

Here is js

```
var quiz = [{
    question: "What is the capital of Turkey?",
    answers: ["Istanbul", "Ankara", "Izmir", "Trabzon"],
    correctAnswer: 1
}, {
    question: "When was Turkey established?",
    answers: [1923, 1928, 1933, 1934],
    correctAnswer: 0
}, {
    question: "What is the population of Turkey?",
    answers: ["90 million", "75 million", "100 million", "80 million"],
    correctAnswer: 1
}, {
    question: "What is the population of Turkey's biggest city, Istanbul?",
    answers: ["18 million", "16 million", "14 million", "7 million"],
    correctAnswer: 2
}]

var i = 0;
var score = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').on('click', function () {
        $('#questions').text(quiz[i].question);
        $('#zero').text(quiz[i].answers[0]);
        $('#one').text(quiz[i].answers[1]);
        $('#two').text(quiz[i].answers[2]);
        $('#three').text(quiz[i].answers[3]);
        $('#start').remove();
        $('.choices').show('slow');
        $('#next').show('slow');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#next', function () {
        var answer = $('input[name="answers"]:checked').val();
        var answerString = quiz[i].answers[answer];
        $('p[class="userAnswer"][value=' + i + ']').text(answerString);
        var correctAnswer = quiz[i].correctAnswer;
        $('p[class="correctAnswer"][value=' + i + ']').text(quiz[i].answers[correctAnswer]);
        if (answer == quiz[i].correctAnswer) {
            score++;
        } else {
            $('tr[class="row"][name=' + i + ']').css('background', '#FE2E64');
        }
        if (!$('input[name="answers"]').is(':checked')) {
            alert("please make a choice");
            return undefined; //stops executing the rest of the code
        }
        i++;

        if (i < 4) {
            $('.choices').css('display', 'none');
            $('#questions').text(quiz[i].question);
            $('#zero').text(quiz[i].answers[0]);
            $('#one').text(quiz[i].answers[1]);
            $('#two').text(quiz[i].answers[2]);
            $('#three').text(quiz[i].answers[3]);
            $('.choices').show('slow');
            $('input[name="answers"]').prop('checked', false);

        }
        if (i > 3) {

            $('#quiz').remove();
            $('#score').text("You have completed the quiz, your score is " + score);//score*(100/i)
            $('.getResult').addClass('show');
            $('#results').fadeIn('fast');
        }

        $('.getResult').on('click', function(){
            window.open('getpdf.php', '_blank')
        })


    });
});
```

and here is my PHP script to convert HTML to pdf

```
<?php
    // Include autoloader 
    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php'; 
    
    // Reference the Dompdf namespace 
    use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
    use Dompdf\Options;

    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('defaultFont', 'Courier');

    // Instantiate and use the dompdf class 
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

    // Load content from html file 
    $html = file_get_contents("index.html"); 
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html); 
    
    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation 
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'potrait'); 
    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();

?>
```

My solution is not working, it's not downloading the current result's, it is downloading the elements which are not dynamically created to the dom.

Now I want when the user clicks the button result to download the results in the pdf file.

What do I need to change to get this working? any idea or solution will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried to spot the problem?

Comment: Your index.html will print without any javascript processing applied. You will need to change the solution approach.

Comment: @kewlashu u mean I just need to use javscript without PHP ?

Comment: No, I meant the opposite, dompdf is running in server side and  $dompdf->loadHtml($html); will not process any javascript, see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219013/is-there-any-way-to-make-javascript-work-in-dompdf-generated-pdfs

Answer (score 1):

I think the dompdf parser cant handle js, and if it does, it doesnt know the answers user have chosen (you can verify this by outputting what you use to feed the domPdf). So better would be just send answers to php script and let it generate html of the pdf which you can then send to dompdf, for generating pdf.

Comment: I think I will try this method because using js pdf there is a lot of limitation's