# Parsing unloaded HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

So I am trying to parse HTMl from a website but all I get is menu because body has a preloader. Links are NSFW so I added a wildcard to them. My question is how do I parse whole page and not only menu? Creating a timeout doesn't seem to help (or I am doing the timeout wrong).

```
<?php
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
        'http' => array( 
            'timeout' => 50
            ) 
        ) 
    ); 
    $stars_list_page = file_get_contents("https://www.por*pics.com/?q=blue+angel", 0, $ctx); 

        $dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom_obj->loadHTML($stars_list_page);
        var_dump($dom_obj);


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 months later I realize how rude I was and didn't answer my own question for future visitors after finding solution.

I went to network tab in developer tools and under XHR I found the URL server is making requests towards to load more data.

If you are having trouble recreating the request try this awesome tool, works with more languages:
https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have menu only, because everything else loaded by js. Thats not going to be simple but you can try to execute js serverside, described here:
[Execute javascript in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php)
But js loading can be domain restricted, so it may not help.