# Need to execute JavaScript with no browser

Tags: javascript, php, api, curl, lumen

I need to make a request with PHP to a URL:
`example.com?price=99&policy=100`.

I am using curl and everything worked fine so far, the problem is that the GET variables are used in the page's JavaScript code in order to send tracking analytics and other stuff. Curl doesn't execute this JavaScript code since is not a JavaScript interpreter. I am building an API, so the function that calls the URL may not be executed by a browser.

Any suggestions on what can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute javascript in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699180/execute-javascript-in-php)

Comment: So you want to load webpage code (HTML) without browser and execute JS which is included inside?

Comment: @Tukkan Yes, basically I need to execute the Javascript code in the called url.

Comment: You may need to install a headless browser to execute client-side code or you may install node to execute it server-side

Comment: Yes, adding onto Johnny's comment, puppeteer is a good library for this - it provides an api to interact with a headless instance of chrome. Because you are using php, you will need to use puphpeteer (https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer)