# If a PHP server script calls a javascript file with a secret key is it exposed?

Tags: javascript, php, security

I want to run a javascript function that needs a secret key to call another remote server.

I don't want that key exposed on the web.

If I make it so that the the javascript function is called by a php function and provided with the secret key that way is it secure?

So web app calls myphpapi.php that runs a CURL script with a secret key parameter to call myjsapi.js?secret=secret (this isn't run in the browser but called by the php script).

Comment: So you would execute the script via node?

Comment: Yah, I am a bit confused here... Where is this JavaScript running?

Comment: If you navigate to `myjsapi.js`, I believe you will realize the first problem with this approach. Why are you trying to run JS from PHP then more PHP? If you explain this flow, maybe we could formulate an answer, or an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the idea is not explained too precisely, the main trick is obviously in *how exactly* you run `myjsapi.js`.

If `myjsapi.js` is a server-side script run for instance, by Node.js  which provides some API & you call an entry point of this API from your PHP, then you just use an internal API.

In this case, it doesn't matter what is the language your internal API is written in. The request will be as secure as your internal API is.

---

If you just have an idea to get content of `myjsapi.js`, you will be able to, yet, it will not be executed. For PHP, your JS code is simply a long string.

If you *really* want to, you could execute that string (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978286/9430588)).

However, you only might want to do it this way only in very specific situations.